# how to convert values of list of list to int in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a list of list, such as

```
T =[[0.10113], [0.56325], [0.02563], [0.09602], [0.06406], [0.04807]]
```

I would like to find the total sum of these numbers.

I am new to python programming, when I try a simple `int(T[1])` conversion, I get error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I appreciate any input.

Comment: The reason you get the error is because `T` is a list, and you access a list's elements using `T[index]`, where `index` is the item you want to grab (in your case, `T[1]` refers to `[0.56325]`). Notice how that element is actually a list itself - in order to reference the number inside of it, you need to pull out the first element of that 'sub-list', as the solutions below show.

Answer (score 2):

easy:

```
sum(x[0] for x in T)
```

You're done :)

---

Of course, you could use

```
import itertools
sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(T))
```

too.  This would work if your sublists had more than 1 element each.

Comment: `sum(zip(*T)[0])` would also work, but I don't think that's terribly easy to read :-)

Comment: This is equivalent to map(sum, T)

Comment: @Alaissham -- How do you figure?  `map` returns a `list`, this returns a scalar value...

Comment: Yeh, `map` returns a `list`.

Comment: @Alaissham: No it is quivalent to `sum(map(operator.itemgetter(0), T))` perhaps, but certainly not `map(sum, T)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for this:

```
sum(map(sum, T))
```

```
>>> sum(map(sum, T))
0.89816000000000007
```

From the documentation for `map`:

> **map**(function, iterable, ...)
>
> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results.

So you are using `map` to total up the inner lists, and then a call to `sum` to total those values for the final answer.

This approach will work if your inner lists contain multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [31]: T =[[0.10113], [0.56325], [0.02563], [0.09602], [0.06406], [0.04807]]

In [32]: sum(t[0] for t in T)
Out[32]: 0.8981600000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> T =[[0.10113], [0.56325], [0.02563], [0.09602], [0.06406], [0.04807]]
>>> sum(x[0] for x in T)
0.8981600000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy sum module

```
 import numpy as np
 result = int(np.sum(T, axis=0))
```

or a inbuilt map function

```
 result = int(sum(map(sum, T)))
```

Comment: Why do you need the axis argument?

Comment: Since, it's a list of list, axis=0 will add the elements of the inner lists, if i don't use axis, it'll sum each inner list and then sum the sums to get a total sum. It's an option in this case

Comment: Your second one won't work.  You can't use `int` on a list/generator as returned from `map`.  You first one is nice, but only if `T` is array-like.  `T = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]` won't work (although that isn't what OP's list looks like)

Comment: @Alaissham -- No, that doesn't work either.  You're just summing the first sublist, not all the sublists.  (It works in this case because `int(0.8)` is still `0`, but that doesn't mean it's right ;^)